# Название Греции

Tags: этимология, топонимика

Откуда в русском (да и не только) языке появилось слово Греция? Ведь самоназвание у страны - Эллада, римляне называли ее Ахайя. Откуда же Греция?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы ошибаетесь насчет римлян. Общее, нейтральное название Греции на латинском - Graecia.
Ахайя или Ахея - термин административный, это название римской провинции, не совсем, кстати, географически соответвующей Элладе.

Answer (score 2):

В словаре Фасмера говорится, что название **Греция** пришло в русский язык из латинского (Graecia) через польский язык (Grecja). Латинское же graecus  произошло от названия иллирийско-эпирского племени (приблизительная транслитерация 'грайхос' или 'грайтос'), жившего на границе Беотии и Аттики (области в Элладе). Название одного племени стало общим названием греков. В русском языке от названия **Греция** произошли *грецкий орех* и *гречка*.

Answer (score -1):

Горица, Гореция — буквально «горная страна», изначальное название Греции, данное ей древними русами тысячелетия назад. Со временем преобразовалось в известное нам «Греция». С греческого и древнегреческого не переводится, т- е. было усвоено местными жителями в готовом виде.

Comment: >С греческого и древнегреческого не переводится, т- е. было усвоено местными жителями в готовом виде.

Местные жители НЕ НАЗЫВАЮТ себя греками. 

Самоназвание - эллин. А страна - Эллос или Эллада.